# Can't send mail from localhost

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to get my developer's license of CF10 to send mail.

```
Mail server: smtp.gmail.com
UserName: xxx
Password: xxx
```

I check "Verify mail server connection" and press 
Submit Changes, and it says 
Connection Verification Successful.

I turned off
"Spool mail messages for delivery" and I'm getting:

> This exception was caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. t39sm8098054anh.3 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use SSL for gmail.
See [here](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Sending_an_Email_through_GMail_With_ColdFusion-16234.html).

Comment: I think I needed to use port="465" as well.  Thanks Dmitry!